# Rails not displaying saving Model property using update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have a Project model. I recently added project_name to that model. When I enter a name into the field and create a new Project however, it doesn't save the new attribute.

Projects Controller:

```
def create
    if project.update_attributes(project_params)
      flash[:success] = 'Project was successfully created'
      redirect_to project_url(project)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:description, :project_name, :customer_number, :sales_number, :sales_id, :customer_id, :discount, :date_wanted, :price, 
                                    items_attributes: [:id, :name, :unit, :quantity, :price, :_destroy])
  end
```

Project Model:

```
include AASM

  STEP_FORWARD_STATE = {
    'quotes'     => :proposal,
    'proposals'  => :ordered,
    'orders'     => :active,
    'in_process' => :close
  }

  STEP_BACK_STATE = {
    'proposals'  => :quoted,
    'orders'     => :proposal,
    'in_process' => :ordered,
    'closed'     => :active
  }

  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :sales, class_name: 'User'

  has_many :curtains, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :versions, class_name: 'ProjectVersion', dependent: :destroy

  has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :drape_tasks, class_name: 'DrapeTask', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :trough_tasks, class_name: 'TroughTask', dependent: :destroy

  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :allow_destroy => true

  delegate :email, :first_name, :full_name, :city_address, :name_for_select,
           :contry_address, :address_for_email, :phone_o,
           to: :customer, prefix: true, :allow_nil => true

  delegate :name_for_select, :address_for_email, :email, :city_address, :full_name, :rep_number, :first_title,
           to: :sales, prefix: true, :allow_nil => true

  validates :customer, :sales, presence: true

  attr_accessor :update_event
```

Terminal Log During the action:

```
Started POST "/projects" for ::1 at 2016-06-08 15:54:57 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+vpCG6JPLLSBtntKhudPTopzq/MH0YlnjlfnFSsOVYnMfRY888LafcReDF41GIxb14q6DLdkbz/AwXEQi+iF4w==", "commit"=>"Create Project", "name"=>"TEST DAMMIT", "customer_autocomplete"=>"test@test.com", "project"=>{"customer_id"=>"1", "sales_id"=>"1", "discount"=>""}, "sales_autocomplete"=>"dzk@dzk", "description_autocomplete"=>"DID IT WORK"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Profile Load (1.8ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."person_id" = $1 AND "profiles"."person_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["person_id", 1], ["person_type", "User"]]
  Project Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" IS NULL  ORDER BY "projects"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Customer Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "customers".* FROM "customers" WHERE "customers"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Profile Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."person_id" = $1 AND "profiles"."person_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["person_id", 1], ["person_type", "Customer"]]
  User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."person_id" = $1 AND "profiles"."person_type" = $2 LIMIT 1  [["person_id", 1], ["person_type", "User"]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "projects" ("state", "sales_id", "customer_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["state", "quotes"], ["sales_id", 1], ["customer_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-06-08 19:54:57.746357"], ["updated_at", "2016-06-08 19:54:57.746357"]]
  Item Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "items".* FROM "items" WHERE "items"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 13]]
  Curtain Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "curtains".* FROM "curtains" WHERE "curtains"."project_id" = $1  [["project_id", 13]]
   (1.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/projects/13
```

EDIT (June 9th):

Thanks for the help so far, @taryn-east .
(Also added my project_params above for clarification)

Here's the form I used for project_name:

```
.form-group
    = label_tag 'name', 'Project Name', class: 'control-label'
    .controls
      = text_field_tag 'name', project.project_name, class: 'form-control', autocomplete: :off
```

For comparison, here's a form used for a working parameter of the model:

```
.form-group
    = label_tag 'customer_autocomplete', 'Customer', class: 'control-label'
    .controls
      = text_field_tag 'customer_autocomplete', project.customer_name_for_select, class: 'form-control customer-autocomplete', autocomplete: :off
      = f.hidden_field :customer_id
```

Clearly, f.hidden_field :[parameter] was missing. I added it to my project_name field, leaving it looking like so:

```
.form-group
    = label_tag 'name', 'Project Name', class: 'control-label'
    .controls
      = text_field_tag 'name', project.project_name, class: 'form-control', autocomplete: :off
      = f.hidden_field :project_name
```

Which now leaves us with a Terminal log of:

```
Started POST "/projects" for ::1 at 2016-06-09 12:11:42 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"BqEZsyQK+uLoeWewYC6smeC6CX0EGLcZgUQlmAyjtLqOmAb3v+2pw6VJ0hoBnISkGegz3fCAMT4+UPMVh28l8Q==", "commit"=>"Create Project", "project_name"=>"TEST PLS DEALER", "project"=>{"project_name"=>"", "customer_id"=>"1", "sales_id"=>"1", "discount"=>"", "description"=>""}, "customer_autocomplete"=>"test@test.com", "sales_autocomplete"=>"dzk@dzk", "description_autocomplete"=>"WORK PLS ONE TIME EHHHH"}
```

This is promising, as adding

```
f.hidden_field :project_name
```

Add project_name to the Project hash passed in the Create action like so:

```
"project"=>{"project_name"=>"", "customer_id"=>"1", "sales_id"=>"1", "discount"=>"", "description"=>""}
```

However, you can see that the actual content of the parameter remains outside the field it is supposed to reside in. I did some digging and noticed the difference between my field and the previous working fields: the working ones had class: "[:parameter]-autocomplete" in them. I added the appropriate class to mine, and it still didn't work. Elsewhere in the app, there's a Coffeescript:

```
$(document).on 'focus', '.customer-autocomplete', ->
  $(@).autocomplete
    source: "/customers",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    minLength: 2,
    select: (event, ui) ->
      $('#project_customer_id').val ui.item.customer_id
      $('#sales_autocomplete').val ui.item.sales_data
      $('#project_sales_id').val ui.item.sales_id
$(document).on 'focus', '.sales-autocomplete', ->
  $(@).autocomplete
    source: "/sales",
    dataType: 'JSON',
    minLength: 2,
    select: (event, ui) ->
      $('#project_sales_id').val ui.item.sales_id
```

I'm not familiar with Coffeescript, but it seems like this is what's auto-completing the hidden fields with class: "[:parameter]-autocomplete". How do I replicate this for my added fields?

EDIT: (June 10th)

I took your advice and simplified the migrations (definitely a good call :) ) but it still seems to be uncooperative. 
New Params:

```
def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:description, :name, :customer_number, :sales_number, :sales_id, :customer_id, :discount, :date_wanted, :price, 
                                    items_attributes: [:id, :name, :unit, :quantity, :price, :_destroy])
  end
```

New Form:

```
.form-group
    = label_tag 'name', 'Project Name', class: 'control-label'
    .controls
      = text_field_tag 'name', project.name, class: 'form-control name-autocomplete', autocomplete: :off
      = f.hidden_field :name
```

New Show:

```
 Project Name:
    = project.name
```

Terminal Log from attempt to make a Project with the above:

```
Started POST "/projects" for ::1 at 2016-06-10 10:30:30 -0400
Processing by ProjectsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iMt4rowEbO1UGzjwfl1XkraTbktC+5+/MiNzYvU/uxAA8mfqF+M/zBkrjVof73+vT8FU67ZjGZiNN6XvfvMqWw==", "commit"=>"Create Project", "name"=>"TEST PROJECT NAME", "project"=>{"name"=>"", "customer_id"=>"1", "sales_id"=>"1", "discount"=>"", "description"=>""}, "customer_autocomplete"=>"test@test.com", "sales_autocomplete"=>"dzk@dzk", "description_autocomplete"=>"TEST PROJECT DESCRIPTION"}
```

I'm having the same issue with project.description as well, as you can see; is it possible the 'project' variable is defined somewhere else in the app that doesn't include these new params? It's not throwing a red screen at any point in the process, either. Thanks again for all the help so far @taryn :)

Comment: What is in `project_params` in your controller, can you post that method? And can you post your form?

Comment: Try `project.reload` after an update or use `update_attributes!` to update project.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the output in the server window it shows you the problem:

```
"name"=>"TEST DAMMIT", "customer_autocomplete"=>"test@test.com",
"project"=>{"customer_id"=>"1", "sales_id"=>"1", "discount"=>""}
```

That name field isn't part of the `project` and thus won't get picked up as an attribute of `project`.

What you'd expect to see coming through from params would be this:

```
"customer_autocomplete"=>"test@test.com",
"project"=>{"name"=>"TEST DAMMIT",  "customer_id"=>"1", "sales_id"=>"1", "discount"=>""}
```

This means that something is slightly wrong with your form. Check that your `name` fields is done the same way as the other project fields

Edit:

In your form, the attributes is named `name`:

```
text_field_tag 'name',
```

but in the rest of your code it's expecting the attribute to be named `project_name`

```
params.require(:project).permit(:description, :project_name
```

You have to actually name the field the same as what you use int he code :) eg

```
text_field_tag 'project_name',
```

though TBH I'd seriously recommend just calling it `name` (and rewriting the migrations etc) if you can because `project.project_name` is a bit redundant ;)

Comment: Thanks, @taryn, that was definitely helpful. I added some new information, what do you think?

Comment: Tried, but that didn't seem to work. Added some more information to see if that helps to clear things up.

Comment: Ok, then there is definitely something wrong with how you are setting up your form. Can you please add the full form, not just the form-group that includes this field?

Comment: oh wait, it's al javascripty auto-completing... yes that will make things complicated...

Comment: However - you can still try actually naming the form-field the way your controller expects. it doesn't expect it to be called `name` (or `project_name`) it expects it to comet through as `project[name]` (or `project[project_name]`) which it then converts into: `:project => {:name}` (or `:project => {:project_name}`) ... in a real form (ie not a javascripty one) it'd get the surrounding `project` scope from the form-action... but in your code you may need to hack it up and actually name the field with `project[name]` or similar.